# AmCharts, stop a 'clickGraphItem' event propagating to 'clickGraph'

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using AmCharts and would like to know how to stop the `clickGraphItem` event propagating to a `clickGraph` event.

The reason I want to stop it is this:

When I click on a bubble in an XY chart I use Mustache to render a little form under the graph with info contained in the `dataContext` of the clicked item.

As there are many bubbles on the plot I would like to be able to highlight the selected item on the bubble chart after it is clicked so as to let the user know what point the info is being edited for.

However if the user clicks in empty space on the graph (the clickGraph event on it's own) I want to fire `event.chart.validateData();` so that the clicked bubble goes back to original colors.

The problem I am encountering is that when I click on the item I get first the `clickGraphItem` event firing but that also triggers the `clickGraph` event.

I have tried to put `event.event.stopPropagation()` at the end of the "Render Mustache and change fill of bubble" method but this does nothing.

The function I am using to handle both events is below:

```
  function showPointForm(event) {
    var ev = event

    if (ev.item && ev.item.dataContext.data != undefined) {
        var bullet = ev.item.bulletGraphics.node;
        bullet.setAttribute("stroke",colors.info);
        bullet.setAttribute("fill",colors.warning);
        $(document).find('#form-area').html(
          Mustache.render($(document).find('#form-template').html(),{
              data : ev.item.dataContext.data
            })
        )
    }else{
      $(document).find('#form-area').html('')
      event.chart.validateData();
    }
  ev.event.stopPropagation()
  }

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart('div',configObject)
chart.addListener("clickGraphItem",showPointForm);
chart.addListener("clickGraph",showPointForm);
```

The idea here is that if the event is from an item, it will change the fill of the bullet and the stroke, and then render a form with some data prop from the item. If the event does not have an item and data, the rendered form get whiped and the chart is redrawn to original styles.

The stopping of event propagation does nothing here to stop the `clickGraph` event being fired

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

SOLUTION:
It turns out that what I was attempting to achieve isn't supported through the standard AmCharts API. The `clickGraph` event will not fire in empty space on a bubble/XY chart. Instead I attached an event in to the `click` event of the `.amcharts-plot-area`.

```
    function showPointForm(event) {
    var ev = event

    if (ev.item && ev.item.dataContext.data != undefined) {
        $(document).find('.highlight').each(function(){
          $(this).attr('class', 'amcharts-graph-bullet');
        })
        var bullet = ev.item.bulletGraphics.node;
        bullet.setAttribute("class",'highlight amcharts-graph-bullet');
        $(document).find('#form-area').html(
          Mustache.render($(document).find('#form-template').html(),{
              data : ev.item.dataContext.data
            })
        )
    }else{
      $(document).find('#form-area').html('')
      event.chart.validateData();
    }
  }

  function reset(){
     $(document).find('#form-area').html('')
     timelineChart.validateData();
  }

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart('div',configObject)
chart.addListener("clickGraphItem",showPointForm);
$(document).on("click",'.amcharts-plot-area',reset);
```

So now when I click on a bubble, all bubbles that were previously styled with the `highlight` class have that class removed. Then the clicked bubble has it added.

When there is a click event in the `amcharts-plot-area` however, the `reset()` function is called which removes all the highlighted classes again.

This solves my issue but as stated below the stopping of event propagation is not possible.

Comment: ev.event.stopPropagation?? a simple `ev.stopPropagation();` will work

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal - No, it won't. AmCharts events contain the native event in a separate property.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to prevent chart event propagation. The chart event name is passed in the `type` property, so you can use that to determine which flow you want. It's not pretty, but that's all you can do:

```
function showPointForm(event) {
  if (event.type == "clickGraphItem") {
   // logic for clickGraphItem only
  }
  else {
    // logic for clickGraph
  }
}
```

You could also set a custom flag inside the chart when the clickGraphItem is fired to indicate that it was just triggered so you know not to perform any additional logic if it was bubbled, for example:

```
function clickGraphHandler(event) {
  if (event.type == "clickGraphItem") {
    event.chart.clickGraphItemFired = true;
    console.log('clickGraphItem')
  } else {
    if (event.chart.clickGraphItemFired) {
      event.chart.clickGraphItemFired = false;
      console.log('clickGraph - bubbled from clickGraphItem');
    } else {
      console.log('clickGraph - not bubbled from clickGraphItem')
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/283664842092af462abcf2f96ca83683?editors=0011)